# PHP SDK library api return blank result

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, github

I have successfully install the domain, already able to login through Facebook, already get these params,

```
$facebook->getUser();
$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

but it hang (return blank result) at this point when the api call this function:

```
$userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId);
```

Is there something wrong with github php sdk?

It seems that I found the problem. When using some restricted user, the information can't be retrieved using that library, but when i use ordinary user account no problem at all.

Yet still the sdk must throw a proper error information. Now who could tell them that?

Answer (score 0):

the server side library of facebook has nothing to do with domain issues - the domain is for the javascript sdk

the reason you don't get the user, is probebly because he didn't allow your application - use javascript sdk's `FB.login` to connect the user to your app

of user the `$facebook->getLoginUrl()` to redirect the user in order to get the `signed_request`/`access_token`/`code` parameters

Comment: but i haven't figure that out, could you give me the example.

Comment: by logic this should working:

<?
if ($userId) { 
 $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId);
?>
Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
<? }?>

but it's giving empty response, which means the library doesn't throw proper response for this matter.